# Wait for transition to end

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx, synchronized

How can I wait for a JavaFx transition to end?

- I have an interactive sorting algorithm.
- Every number is represented by a rectangle.
- When two numbers are swapped the rectangles must be swap.

The problem is that animation duration is 1s and in this time the entire array is already sorted. I already made an synchronized method that swaps the rectangles. But when it make "transition.play();"

I think that transition is running in another thread so it must wait  for transition to end before ending that method.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are sorting the array. If you can sort it step by step, then perform one step of the sort, then start a single animation. Since you know the duration is 1 second, just sleep for 1 second and then do another step of the sort. Continue until the entire array is sorted.

If JavaFx allows you to receive callbacks when an animation has finished, then listen for the callback to know when you can begin the next step of the sort.

Comment: If i sleep 1s the user interface freezes.

Comment: Okay, so does JavaFx let you know when the animation has ended? (I've never used it). Sleeping won't work, so just let the control go back to the UI framework, then respond to a callback about the animation. It's definitely going to be an asynchronous, callback-driven design .

Comment: JavaFx let me do something like this: timeline2.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                setRectangleFill(rectangle2, Color.BLACK);
                rectangle2.setX(rectangle1X);
            }
        });

Comment: Excellent, then you can use `setOnFinished` to call the next step of your array sort algorithm.

Comment: I already making something like this but it doesn't work. Look at this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131783/java-volatile-variable-is-not-updating

Comment: Found an [answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188018/how-to-wait-for-a-transition-to-end-in-javafx-2-1). Look at the response by Uluk Biy.

Comment: The sorting algorithm is independent. When two variables are swapped, the rectangles are swaped. What should I put on the setOnFinished method? Look at this post and you will see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131783/java-volatile-variable-is-not-updating