# Java - volatile variable is not updating

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx, volatile

I'm working on an interactive sorting application in JavaFx:

- The numbers are represented by rectangles
- Every time two numbers are swapped the rectangles are swapped(using timeline - animation)

This is one of the sorting algorithms:

```
 public class BubbleSort implements SortAlgorithm {
private volatile Boolean swaping;

public void sort(double[] array, CompareFunction compareFunction, Model model, Controller controller) {
    Boolean ord;
    int i;
    double aux;

    swaping = false;

    do {
        ord = true;

        for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (compareFunction.compare(array[i], array[i + 1]) == false) {
                while (swaping);

                swaping = true;

                aux = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = aux;
                ord = false;

                controller.swapRectangles(model.getRectangles().get(i), model.getRectangles().get(i + 1), this);
            }
        }
    } while (ord == false);
}

public void setSwaping(Boolean swaping) {
    this.swaping = swaping;
}
```

}

This is the prototype of the swapRectangles method:

```
public void swapRectangles(final Rectangle rectangle1, final Rectangle rectangle2,    final BubbleSort bubbleSort)
```

And when timeline ends I udpate "swaping" value:

```
        timeline2.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            setRectangleFill(rectangle2, Color.BLACK);
            rectangle2.setX(rectangle1X);
            bubbleSort.setSwaping(false);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the "swaping" variable is never updating(the setSwaping method is never called).

Do you know why?

Comment: How you know its not updating?

Comment: Because application freezes. After "swaping" becomes "true" it not pass from "while (swaping);".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Running `while(swaping);` puts a hard pressure on processor, you are taking all it's power and give it to "do-nothing" loop. To solve that either add sleep inside: `while(swaping) Thread.sleep(100);` or use more convenient synchronization mechanism like [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)
2. Also if you run `sort` on UI thread you block it entirely, thus `setOnFinished` will never get a chance to be run. You should run `sort` on a separate thread:

   ```
   new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           new BubbleSort().sort(array, compareFunction, model, controller);
       }
   }.start();
   ```

If you update UI from this thread, make sure you wrap UI calls into [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 0):

I think you update `swaping = true` in `setSwaping` method but in sort method you again set `swaping= false` before while loop execute. So I think your while loop is never executing since swaping is false. So you assuming that value is not being updating.

Remove this line from your `sort` method:

```
swaping = false;


while (swaping);
```

remove `;` and put your code inside while block.

Comment: The application freezes after first swap. When "swaping" becomes "true", at the next "swap" will never pass by "while(swaping);".

Comment: I removed that line and the application still freezes.

Comment: No, I put there ";" because the animation's duration is 1s and "the next swap" must wait for animation to end.

Comment: @JohnSmith but that causes infinite loop if swaping is true.

Comment: Yes, but I update "swaping" here:        timeline2.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            setRectangleFill(rectangle2, Color.BLACK);
            rectangle2.setX(rectangle1X);
            bubbleSort.setSwaping(true);
        }
    });

Comment: When the animation is finished, I update "swaping". I already said this on post.

Comment: So, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry I dont understand your problem properly.

Comment: When the algorithm swaps two elements, the user interface is updated: the rectangles associated to that elements are swapped(using an animation) over 1 second. When the animation ends, the "swaping" is set to false, so the next swap must begin.

Comment: Sorry, bad code provided. Actually, the updating method sets "swaping" value to "false":  "bubbleSort.setSwaping(false);". I changed this but it still doesn't work. You can look at the post to see the good code now.

Comment: @JohnSmith You are using multithreading...yes? Try printing value of swapping inside setSwaping method.

Comment: Yes, something like this. I think that animation is running in another thread. Anyway, it doesn't prints anything. It is never called I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28603/discussion-between-achintya-jha-and-john-smith)