# In order transition on ImageView in JavaFX

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx-2, javafx

I have already looked at [How to wait for a transition to end in javafx 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188018/how-to-wait-for-a-transition-to-end-in-javafx-2-1) but it doesn't quite solve my problem.

I have a List of ImageView objects, and I want to iterate through this List and perform the following actions on each 'slide' of the List:

1. fade in
2. stay for a few seconds
3. fade out

I have the following code in place but since the transition is asynchronous, the loop applies the transition to all the 'slides' at the same time:

```
// The method I am running in my class

public void start() {

    for (ImageView slide : slides) {

        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();

        FadeTransition fadeIn = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 0.0, 1.0, 2000);
        FadeTransition stayOn = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 1.0, 2000);
        FadeTransition fadeOut = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 0.0, 2000);

        sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);               
        this.root.getChildren().add(slide);            
        sequentialTransition.play();

    }
}

// the method in the Transition helper class:

public static FadeTransition getFadeTransition(ImageView imageView, double fromValue, double toValue, int durationInMilliseconds) {

    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(durationInMilliseconds), imageView);
    ft.setFromValue(fromValue);
    ft.setToValue(toValue);

    return ft;

}
```

Any ideas on how I can animate these List of ImageView objects one by one (irrespective of the number of ImageViews there are on the List, so I do not want to hard code it). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the obivous fix to this would be to use a surrounding SequentialTransition for your SequentialTransitions that plays those Transitions, well, sequentially instead of all at once:

```
public void start() {

    SequentialTransition slideshow = new SequentialTransition();

    for (ImageView slide : slides) {

        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();

        FadeTransition fadeIn = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 0.0, 1.0, 2000);
        FadeTransition stayOn = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 1.0, 2000);
        FadeTransition fadeOut = Transition.getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 0.0, 2000);

        sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);               
        this.root.getChildren().add(slide);            
        slideshow.getChildren().add(sequentialTransition);

    }
    slideshow.play();
}
```

Second, you should use PauseTransition instead of a FadeTransition that interpolates from 1.0 to 1.0.

A full example application of this could look like this:

```
package slideshow;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SimpleSlideShowTest extends Application{

  class SimpleSlideShow {

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    ImageView[] slides;

    public SimpleSlideShow() {
      this.slides = new ImageView[4];
      Image image1 = new Image(SlideShowTest.class.getResource("pic1").toExternalForm());
      Image image2 = new Image(SlideShowTest.class.getResource("pic2").toExternalForm());
      Image image3 = new Image(SlideShowTest.class.getResource("pic3").toExternalForm());
      Image image4 = new Image(SlideShowTest.class.getResource("pic4").toExternalForm());
      slides[0] = new ImageView(image1);
      slides[1] = new ImageView(image2);
      slides[2] = new ImageView(image3);
      slides[3] = new ImageView(image4);

    }

    public StackPane getRoot() {
      return root;
    }

    // The method I am running in my class

    public void start() {

      SequentialTransition slideshow = new SequentialTransition();

      for (ImageView slide : slides) {

        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();

        FadeTransition fadeIn = getFadeTransition(slide, 0.0, 1.0, 2000);
        PauseTransition stayOn = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
        FadeTransition fadeOut = getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 0.0, 2000);

        sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);
        slide.setOpacity(0);
        this.root.getChildren().add(slide);
        slideshow.getChildren().add(sequentialTransition);

      }
      slideshow.play();
    }

// the method in the Transition helper class:

    public FadeTransition getFadeTransition(ImageView imageView, double fromValue, double toValue, int durationInMilliseconds) {

      FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(durationInMilliseconds), imageView);
      ft.setFromValue(fromValue);
      ft.setToValue(toValue);

      return ft;

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    SimpleSlideShow simpleSlideShow = new SimpleSlideShow();
    Scene scene = new Scene(simpleSlideShow.getRoot());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    simpleSlideShow.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! :) I haven't tried that (will do when I get home) but it makes sense lol.. i am so stupid.. thanks so much! :) I will update you once I get home..

Comment: No problem. If I might add, I would rather use Timer and TimerTask to trigger the next slides apart from JavaFX, because this scales much better. I wrote a slideshow for myself a few weeks ago, and adding buttons and or stopping the slideshow is something you might want to add later to your application.

Comment: Hi Bastian, I tried the solution you suggested and unfortunately it doesn't quite do the trick. When I run the code, I only see the last slide in the list.. it shows up front and then it fades in and fades out leaving the screen to blank. I think I need to play the transition for each slide which is not happening here.. any ideas? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SoftwareGuy: i don't know what you're missing but i posted a complete example that shows the slideshow. notice the `setOpacity(0)` for each slide.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian :) I did not use the setOpacity method. I am going to try it out later in the eve and update you. Many thanks for putting up the complete sample code. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Awesssomeee @Sebastian :) slide.setOpacity(0); was the missing piece! thanks a million man! you rock!

Comment: I tried to play image from URL but it gives me null pointer at 'setOpacity(0)' can you help me? how it gets error?

Comment: @Sebastian - I am trying to write a slideshow app for my own purposes. Eventually, I'd like to be able to hit a key when a slide is up, and have the image file that was loaded into the slide simply delete or move to another folder. I was going to play with the code you posted, but I think I am going to need the SlideShowTest class in order to fully examine how this code works. Would you be able to post this class for me?